# INSERT into database from form, returns value 1 and not input text

Tags: php, sql

As the title says.

The form or my query is playing a trick on me :(

It enter a 1 inside my database instead of what Im writing in the form.

This is my form

```
<form action="deleteupdate.php" method="post">
<div id="txtHint"></div>
<input type ="submit" name="submittype" value ="Delete">
<input type ="submit" name="submittype" value ="Update">
category: <input type="text" name="category" />
</form>
```

And the query in deleteupdate.php

```
else if($_POST['submittype']=="Update"){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `category`(`category`) 
    VALUES (category='$category')") ; 
    }
```

Shouldn't this work ?

Comment: [`mysql_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$category doesn't exist in your script.
Use this code:

```
else if($_POST['submittype']=="Update"){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `category`(`category`) 
        VALUES ('". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']) ."')") ; 
}
```

Comment: That solved the problem, I'm almost sure that I tried that. but almost sure just become. I dint tried that query :) 

THANK YOU

Comment: Just waiting for the minutes ;)

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `category`(`category`) 
    VALUES ('". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['category']) ."')") ;
```

Comment: +1 for notice that I didn't had secure it.

But now it just save and empty column in the database